# How to extract a specific type of number from a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Consider this  string:

```
text = '''
4 500,5

12%

1,63%

568768,74832 days in between

34 cars in a row'''
```

As you can see, there are simple numbers, numbers with spaces in between, numbers with comas, and both. Thus, `4 500,5` is considered as a standalone, separate number. Extracting the numbers with comas and spaces is easy and I found the pattern as:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+ )?\d+,\d+')
```

However, I am struggling to extract just the simple numbers like 12 and 34. I tried using `(?!...)` and `[^...]` but these options do not allow me to exclude the unwanted parts of other numbers.

Comment: Do you want to extract just all numbers into a single list? Or into separate lists? What is the expected output?

Comment: How close is `(\d+ )?\d+,\d+|(\d+(?! \d))` to what you want?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, into a single list. The expected output is a whole number, such as 12 and 34. Consider that a one digit number must also be captured.

Comment: I think you can use `re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d\s)(?:\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*|\d+)(?:,\d+)?(?!\s\d{3}\b|\d)', text)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZpKNQ/1)

Comment: Judging by your [other comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899452/how-to-extract-a-specific-type-of-number-from-a-string-using-regex-in-python#comment123560617_69899537), you want to get two lists: 1) those with fractions and 2) intergers. Right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct!

Comment: To match integers, you can use https://regex101.com/r/hZpKNQ/4 and https://regex101.com/r/hZpKNQ/5 is for floats.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's not very clear from the question what the answer should be, but consider posting those 2 patterns. I don't remember seeing one for the integer before.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I do not think that is well-tested though, I will check and if they work well, I will post. I will have to remove the comment (since it will be removed most probably anyway).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, this does it too. You should post this and i will mark it as a solution since it more closely aligns with what I initially wanted than Joshua's answer down there.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your answer was also a solution. Thank you for your inputs!

Comment: @Rufat I have restored the answer to match only 12 and 34. Keep an eye on this thread as there might be better answers posted.

Comment: I am inclined to think `(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:[ \xA0]\d{3})*|\d+)(?:,\d+)?(?!\d)` is the best pattern to match all numbers, and later filter out whatever type of numbers you need.

Answer (score 3):

`((?:\d+ )?\d+,\d+)|(\d+(?! \d))`

I believe this will do what you want (Regexr link: https://regexr.com/695tc)

To capture "simple" numbers, it looks for [one or more digits], which are not followed by [a space and another digit].

I edited so that you can use capture groups appropriately, if desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works, however, I was wondering if there is a way to capture specifically 12, 34 and other *whole* numbers and not the decimal ones?

Comment: @Rufat You can filter out the resulting list from numbers containing `,` later, it will be much simpler.

Comment: Is `1,234` a whole number? (One thousand two hundred thirty-four?) or is it a decimal number? (One point two three four?)

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp Thousand separators are spaces in the OP input.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp In my case, "One thousand two hundred thirty-four" would look like this: 1 234.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That makes sense!

Comment: @Rufat I do not think this regex will work for all cases. Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/hZpKNQ/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew True, however, it seems like no other option works for your example here, even those that you proposed up there. In any case you guys are regex gods :D

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to match 12 and 34:

```
(?<!\S)\d+\b(?![^\S\n]*[,\d])
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\d+\b` Match 1+ digits and a word boundary
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

  - `[^\S\n]*[,\d]` Match optional spaces and either `,` or a digit
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/irL2Nf/1)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest extracting all numbers first, then filter those with a comma to a list with floats, and those without a comma into a list of integers:

```py
import re
text = '4 500,5\n\n12%\n\n1,63%\n\n568768,74832 days in between\n\n34 cars in a row'
number_rx = r'(?<!\d)(?:\d{1,3}(?:[ \xA0]\d{3})*|\d+)(?:,\d+)?(?!\d)'
number_list = re.findall(number_rx, text)
print('Float: ', [x for x in number_list if ',' in x])
# => Float:  ['4 500,5', '1,63', '568768,74832']
print('Integers: ', [x for x in number_list if ',' not in x])
# => Integers:  ['12', '34']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Ea7sth) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2npCyl/1).

The regex matches:

- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that allows no digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?:\d{1,3}(?:[ \xA0]\d{3})*|\d+)` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\d{1,3}(?:[ \xA0]\d{3})*` - one, two or three digits, and then zero or more occurrences of a space / hard (no-breaking) space followed with three digits
  - `|` - or
  - `\d+`  - one or more digits
- `(?:,\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and then one or more digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that allows no digit immediately to the right of the current location.